# How to make a Mock Test for OAUTH Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I want to make a test case with Mock for Spring Boot but i am unable to connect to authorization server:

My Controller:

```
public class AuthController {

@Autowired
private AuthService authService;

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@PostMapping(value = Constants.LOGIN_URL,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Auth login(@RequestBody Auth login, OAuth2Authentication auth) throws ApiException {

    Auth result = authService.auth(login);

    final OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
    result.setAccessToken(details.getTokenValue());
    final OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(details.getTokenValue());
    result.setTtl(accessToken.getExpiresIn());

    return result;
}
```

This is My Test, but take an error NullPointer, Maybe is because in the method have a parameter (OAuth2Authentication auth) and i dont know how put this into the test:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)                
          .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.jUnitRestDocumentation))
          .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver()).build();
}

@Test
public void getLogin() throws Exception, ApiException {

   Auth authMock = Mockito.mock(Auth.class);
   Mockito.when(service.auth(Mockito.any(Auth.class))).thenReturn(authMock);

    String requestBody = "{" +
            "\"username\":" + "\"YENNIFER\"" +
            ",\"nid\":" + "\"13991676\"" +
            ",\"password\":" + "\"password\"" +
            ",\"email\":" + "\"cervecera.artesanal@gmail.com\"" +
            "}";

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/v1/auth/login")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(requestBody))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far in a test?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to test?

Comment: I try test the login service and i want test the get token too

Comment: How i test the get token?  "http://localhost:8080/auth/token"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply mock `AuthService` and inject that mock into the controller, e.g.:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AuthControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private AuthService authService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AuthController controller;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAuth() {
        Auth authMock = Mockito.mock(Auth.class);
        Mockito.when(authService.auth(Mockito.any(Auth.class)).thenReturn(auth));
    }
}
```

Comment: How i agree the perform ?

Comment: @Guerra added `@Before` method, try now?

Comment: Not work,  java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sodexo.oneapp.api.auth.AuthControllerTest.getLogin(AuthControllerTest.java:72)

Comment: I think is a  (OAuth2Authentication auth) parameter in the controller, how i add to my test?